# iOS7 Silent Push notification not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I have implement push notifications in iOS7. As iOS7 having features of receiving push notification silently by using method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
}
```

But this method never getting called as I am sending notification. I am receiving the notification in notification tray But notification should not be there as It is silent. I am using Raywenderlich's PHP code to send the push Notification. I have added content-available key also like this

```
// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
    'content-available' => '1',
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: There are several reasons for that, first check your server log that is it able to send the message successfully to Apple server? or you are having this problem only in IOS 7

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct certificate and device token? In debug mode you need to use the debug certificate and the device token is different than the one you have in production. Also if you want a push to be silent, the sound value should be omitted AFAIK. Finally you can test pushes easy, by using Urbanairship instead of writing your own php implementation

Comment: I am receiving the notification.. no issue in that... But not receiving silent notification

Comment: I dont want to show the notification to user..

Comment: Have you registered UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability for silent push notification like you did for alert, badge and sound?

Comment: Yes I have registered for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability

Comment: If you don't want to show notification just ignore the "alert" in your payload.

Comment: Notification delegate method not getting called in that case @Nandha

Comment: Your question is then misleading, as you say the delegate method is never called. How can you receive the notification if the delegate method is never called?

Comment: I was receiving the notification as it was showing in notification tray.. The delegate method for handling push notfication content is not getting called..

Comment: Gopesh, Have you registered UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability for silent push notification?

Comment: @Nandha Yes I have done. This silent push notification doing headache to me from last two days...

Comment: Ok, Have you enabled background mode for "remote-notification" in ur plist file?

Comment: Oops, Mavericks updated his answer. Follow that process.

Comment: @Nandha I have done that one also. I am also wondered why it's happening? it is very simple....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43985/discussion-between-gopesh-gupta-and-nandha)

Comment: Good to Know @Gopesh. can you share what caused this issue?

Comment: @Nandha sorry for late replying, actually delegate method syntax was different as you can check written above....

Answer (score 3):

You should not add 'alert' param in your payload if you want to silent push notification.

pass your param like this.

```
$body['aps'] = array(
'content-available' => '1'
);
```

And verify you enabled remote-notification in your project plist.

[image]

or

[image]

You will get notification by implementing this delegate.

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
// Call or write any code necessary to download new data.
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this..now getting no notification when app in background.. it is not calling - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
} in background mode

Comment: Check my updated answer. Follow this link for more info. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-mutlitasking-enhancements/?search_index=2

Comment: want to notify one thing... in case of foreground, this method getting called - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

Answer (score 1):

Try with a integer value :

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'content-available' => 1,
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
```